# Split by commas but not within brackets using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string by commas, but not when they're inside brackets.

For instance:

```
"[1, '15', [false]], [[], 'sup']"
```

would split into

```
[
  "[1, '15', [false]]",
  "[[], 'sup']"
]
```

I've tried `/\,(?=(.*\[.*\])*.*\]{1})/` for my regexp, my logic is match commas that aren't followed by an even number of '[]' with any characters in between and outside followed by one ']'.

Comment: Are the array literals at first example valid arrays?

Comment: @guest271314: OP says they have a *string*, so presumable this is the content of a string.

Comment: @FelixKling _"but not when they're inside an array element"_ Given initial string, how to determine which is array element? Split at comma at `]],[[`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion the whole thing is a string

Comment: Should resulting string be parseable as a `javascript`  object or valid `JSON`? Or only return result described at OP?

Comment: Only return result described as op.

Answer (score 6):

Regexp is not well-suited to situations like this involving nesting. You might want to write a tiny parser:

```js
function parse(str) {
  let result = [], item = '', depth = 0;

  function push() { if (item) result.push(item); item = ''; }

  for (let i = 0, c; c = str[i], i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!depth && c === ',') push();
    else {
      item += c;
      if (c === '[') depth++;
      if (c === ']') depth--;
    }
  }
  
  push();
  return result;
}
        
console.log(parse("[1, '15', [false]], [[], 'sup']"));
```

You may want to tweak this to handle spaces around the commas, unbalanced square brackets, etc.

Comment: This is really nice thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

If expected result are two strings, irrespective of whether or not strings are parseable as `javascript` object or valid `JSON` you can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `String.prototype.split()`, `String.prototype.replace()`

```js
var str = "[1, '15', [false]], [[], 'sup']";

var res = str.split(/,/).reduce((arr, text) => {

  text = text.trim();

  if (arr.length === 0) {
    arr.push([]);
  }
 
  if (/^\[/.test(text) && !/\]$/.test(text)) {
     arr[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1].push(text.slice(1));
     return arr
  }
 
  if (!/^\[/.test(text) && /\]$/.test(text)) {
     arr[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1].push(text.slice(0, -1));
     return arr
  }

  if (!/^\[/.test(text) && !/\]$/.test(text) 
      || /^\[/.test(text) && /\]{2}$/.test(text) 
      || !/\[|\]/.test(text)) {
      arr[arr.length === 1 ? 0 : arr.length - 1].push(text);
     return arr
  }
  
  if (/^\[{2}/.test(text) && /\]$/.test(text)) {
     arr[arr.length - 1].push(text);
     return arr
  }

  return arr

}, []);

var strs = `[${res.join()}]`.replace(/"/g, "").split(/,(?=\[{2})|"(?=")/);

console.log(`str1:${strs[0]}\nstr2:${strs[1]}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If string is proper array-like string... maybe this is worth a try, too:

```
 var regex = /(\[.*?\]\])|(\[\[.*?\]$)|(\[(.*?)\])|(,)/gm;
```

```js
var regex = /(\[.*?\]\])|(\[\[.*?\]$)|(\[(.*?)\])|(,)/gm;
str = "[1, '15', [false]], [[], 'sup']";
/*str="[1, [30] [false][,]], [[]false, 'sup'[]]";
str="[[] []], [1,4,5[8]]";
str="[[1,2,3],[3,6,7]],[[],566,[]]";
str="[[],[]],['duh,[],'buh',[]]";

str="[1,2,3],[5,'ggg','h']"*/


arr=[];
while ((matches = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
if(matches[0]!==',')
arr.push(matches[0]);

  
}

console.log(arr);
```

So, basically, match alternative groups, loop through results, keep non-comma matches. This will fail, probably, in some cases...but, should be tested more.